# Specifying a tooltip location

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on this website: http://india.kentlewis.net/book1.html.

I've got a series of thumbnails displayed in a chart. I've got the page configured so that `onmouseover`, the full-sized image pops up as a `tooltip` box. The problem is that the images are 800x600, so with the chart in the middle of the screen at least part of the image is always off-screen.

I'm looking for a way to make the pop-up appear in a specific place (say the upper left-hand corner of the screen) no matter the cursor location.

Comment: india.kentlewis.net/book1.html

Comment: maybe you shouldn't use `mouseover` to display the images if they are that big. The reason being that no matter where you have the thumbnail some part of the image is going to be off the screen as you have seen it. And if you move your mouse then you end up hovering over another thumbnail. Change the function to be `onclick` and then you should be able to position the image wherever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be a problem with using mouseover: if the larger image appears on mouseover in a fixed location, it would be nearly impossible to ensure that it does not cover the location of the thumbnail; and when it does your cursor is no longer over the thumbnail (rather it's over the larger image). and the image would automatically hide again.

So if you want a fixed position for the larger image, I'd recommend using/writing another script that opens the image on click, with a "close image" -type link. Lightbox scripts are typically how this is done.

**The original lightbox**:
[Lighbox 2](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/)  -- by Lokesh Dhakar "...a simple, unobtrusive script used to overlay images on the current page. It's a snap to setup and works on all modern browsers."  (I beleive this is the 2nd version of the 'origal' lightbox script)

**My recommendation** (the one I use -- lighter, more standards compliant):
[Slimbox 2](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2) -- by Christophe Beyl "...is a 4 KB visual clone of the popular Lightbox 2 script by Lokesh Dhakar, written using the jQuery javascript library. It was designed to be very small, efficient, standards-friendly, fully customizable, more convenient and 100% compatible with the original Lightbox 2."

Answer (score 0):

please try by giving the following styles to popup

```
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px
```